# Bring nested name into scope in non-member function

Tags: c++, c++17, using-directives

I have a struct B that contains the declaration of a type `anchor_point` as a nested name. How can I bring `anchor_point` into scope in another function using the `using`-directive? I basically want to access the type as is without qualifiying it (just like from within a member function). I tried the following (see comments):

[CODE](https://godbolt.org/z/o44P74K59)

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
    struct anchor_point
    {
        int a_;
    };
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    // Here's what I want - doesn't compile
    // using B;
    // anchor_point ap1{5};

    // This gets laborious if there are dozens of types inside of B
    B::anchor_point ap2{5};

    // This is even more laborious
    using ap_t = B::anchor_point;
    ap_t ap3{5};

    std::cout << ap2.a_ << ", " << ap3.a_ << "\n";
}
```

The example is dumbed down but let's say I have a few dozens of those types declared inside the struct and I don't always want to type `B::type`, how can I do this?

Comment: Instead of searching for a better syntax, you should start thinking about your design! The idea of objects is not to expose all and everything around and accessing the last bit of data deep inside a nested struct from any unrelated function. If you tag with c++17 but access your data like in assembler language, there is something totally wrong!

Comment: This is a design issue. If you have a nested class, that should be for a reason, it's not intended to be used separately. If `B` was a `namespace` this would be different, but since it's a `class`, `anchor_point` is or should be tightly coupled to `B`. Note that `using anchor_point = B::anchor_point;` is perfectly legal (but confusing). If you think that's "laborious", you're programming in the wrong language.

Comment: @JHBonarius If you ignore any standard idioms and standard practice on any given language, you will find all and everything "laborious" in any language :-) It is quite clear that OP is on the wrong track... in hope this comments are the startpoint to become a programmer and leave the coders world :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have shown you can do

```
using anchor_point = B::anchor_point;
```

repeated for every relevant member. This has to appear only once in the scope enclosing all your uses of the member that you want to cover.

There is no other way, in particular no equivalent to `using namespace` for namespaces which makes all members visible to unqualified name lookup.